# How to work with style Index in Open xml?

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, spreadsheetml

Can Anyone please explain How Style Index in OpenXml works?
I have a business requirement where I need to apply background color to certain cells in an excel sheet. And Some style is already applied to other cells. So I need to decide which style Index I need to apply.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

OpenXML styling can be confusing when you take the first look at it.  Excel document styling falls under the `SpreadsheetML` markup language, which is different from Word and PowerPoint..

For typical cells in Excel, the only style information required is the StyleIndex (as you pointed out).

```
Cell cell16 = new Cell(){ CellReference = "HU1", StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U, DataType = CellValues.SharedString };
```

This corresponds to the s attribute in the XML:

```
      <x:c r="HU1" s="1" t="s">
        <x:v>0</x:v>
      </x:c>
```

The `StyleIndex` is the zero-based index of the `CellFormat` record in the Styles part.

The styles part (aka the Stylesheet of the workbook) contains the following sections:

- Numbering Formats
- Fonts
- Fills
- Borders
- Cell Style Formats
- Cell Formats **<== cell styleindex is referring to one of these**
- Cell Styles
- Differential Formats
- Table Styles
- Colors
- Stylesheet Extention List

Now inside the `CellFormat` record, there are references that refer back out to each of the following sections in the stylesheet:

1. Numbering Format (first bullet above)
2. Font (second bullet above)
3. Fill (third bullet above)
4. Border (fourth bullet above)

An example cell format in code looks like:

```
// this line is important to your question
CellFormat cellFormat5 = new CellFormat(){ NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)0U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)11U, 
//the rest of the CellFormat definition is not so important to your question
FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, ApplyFill = true, ApplyBorder = true, ApplyAlignment = true };
```

To answer your question:  *apply a certain background color to certain cells* .  Let say we want to update cell `B3` of your spreadsheet and `B3` already has `StyleIndex` of `10`.

You will need to follow these steps:

Step 1.  If this is a new background color to the spreadsheet, add the background (aka `Fill`) to the `Fills` section of the Stylesheet (third bullet above) that contains your new color.  If the color already exists, you need to find and remember the index of the existing `Fill` for that color.  Either way, for this example lets say the `Fill` index you requre is `25`.

Step 2.  Create a new `CellFormat` that is a copy of the `CellFormat` at index `10`.  You will add this new `CellFormat` to the end of the `CellFormat` section.  Lets say the index of the new `CellFormat` will be `53`.

Step 3. You update the `CellFormat` at index `53` and make its `Fill` index property be `25` (from Step 1).

Last Step:  Update the Cell in question `B3`, to have a new `StyleIndex` of `53`

**Note**: This answer is for non-table cell styling in Excel - if you want styling information for table cells, please reply and Ill try and update or add an answer for it.

This answer comes mainly out of my experience and also interpretation of pages 73-79 of the free e-book: **[Open XML - The markup explained](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2007/08/13/1970.aspx)** - by Wouter van Vugt.  It is a good reference to use for all OpenXml.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was indeed helpful.

Comment: @Taterhead, yes please. Can you update the answer to include a way to do it for table data. That would be great!

Comment: @Abhi7950 - it is better that you ask a separate question on the site with your specific problem.  Myself and others will help you solve it quickly.  Please reference this question in your post and put a link to the q in a comment reply below here.

Comment: `CellFormat` or `CellFormats` ? I have sample document, which is used two `CellFormats` and the first one has one `CellFormat` and the other, three `CellFormat`s inside of it. You wrote `CellFormat` but then point to > `Cell Formats <== cell styleindex is referring to one of these`

Comment: CellFormats is a collection of CellFormat xml entities.  Because you have two of them in your sample document, might mean you have multiple stylesheets for that workbook.