# Add stylesheet to openxml excel file

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to insert some styles in a excel file. Right now the data part works perfectly, but the style throws an error when I open the excel. It complains that the stylesheet file has an error in line 19 of the xml. I don't know what is wrong with that line. It is where the font collection node start.
Any ideas why...
This is the xml for the style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x:styleSheet xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" mc:Ignorable="x14ac">
    <x:borders count="1">
        <x:border>
            <x:left style="thin">
                <x:color indexed="64" rgb="000000" />
            </x:left>
            <x:right style="thin">
                <x:color indexed="64" rgb="000000" />
            </x:right>
            <x:top style="thin">
                <x:color indexed="64" rgb="000000" />
            </x:top>
            <x:bottom style="thin">
                <x:color indexed="64" rgb="000000" />
            </x:bottom>
        </x:border>
    </x:borders>
    <x:fonts count="1">
        <x:font>
            <x:b />
            <x:sz val="12" />
            <x:color rgb="000000" />
            <x:name val="Arial" />
        </x:font>
    </x:fonts>
    <x:cellXfs>
        <x:xf fontId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf fontId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf fontId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf fontId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf fontId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf fontId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf fontId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf fontId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf fontId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf fontId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf fontId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="0" applyBorder="1" />
    </x:cellXfs>
</x:styleSheet>
```

**UPDATE**

After some testing, googling, head banging.... I came up with the following stylesheet xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x:styleSheet xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:x16r2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/02/main" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" mc:Ignorable="x14ac x16r2 xr">
    <x:fonts count="2" x14ac:knownFonts="1">
        <x:font />
        <x:font>
            <x:b />
            <x:sz val="12" />
            <x:color rgb="FF000000" />
            <x:name val="Arial" />
            <x:family val="2" />
            <x:scheme val="minor" />
        </x:font>
    </x:fonts>
    <x:borders count="2">
        <x:border />
        <x:border>
            <x:left style="thin">
                <x:color rgb="FF000000" />
            </x:left>
            <x:right style="thin">
                <x:color rgb="FF000000" />
            </x:right>
            <x:top style="thin">
                <x:color rgb="FF000000" />
            </x:top>
            <x:bottom style="thin">
                <x:color rgb="FF000000" />
            </x:bottom>
        </x:border>
    </x:borders>
    <x:cellXfs count="3">
        <x:xf />
        <x:xf fontId="1" borderId="1" applyFont="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf borderId="1" applyBorder="1" />
    </x:cellXfs>
</x:styleSheet>
```

Still excel complains that the file is corrupt after recovering the file it displays the styles applied to each cell gives the error "Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)" .
LibreOffice opens the file correctly, OPEN XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool validates the file as correct...Why excel complains.....

**UPDATE**
After playing around with the code I solved the problem.
This two questions also helped
[Stylesheet 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116176/cell-styles-in-openxml-spreadsheet-spreadsheetml)
[Stylesheet 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839512/how-to-work-with-style-index-in-open-xml)

It seems that there is an order to create the nodes, specially the cellStyleXfs and cellXfs, the cellStyleXfs as to come before the cellXfs

The working XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x:styleSheet xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:x16r2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/02/main" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" mc:Ignorable="x14ac x16r2 xr">
    <x:fonts count="3" x14ac:knownFonts="1">
        <x:font />
        <x:font>
            <x:b />
            <x:sz val="12" />
            <x:color rgb="FF000000" />
            <x:name val="Arial" />
            <x:family val="2" />
            <x:scheme val="minor" />
        </x:font>
        <x:font>
            <x:b />
            <x:sz val="12" />
            <x:color rgb="FFFF0000" />
            <x:name val="Arial" />
            <x:family val="2" />
            <x:scheme val="minor" />
        </x:font>
    </x:fonts>
    <x:fills count="1">
        <x:fill />
    </x:fills>
    <x:borders count="2">
        <x:border />
        <x:border>
            <x:left style="thin">
                <x:color rgb="FF000000" />
            </x:left>
            <x:right style="thin">
                <x:color rgb="FF000000" />
            </x:right>
            <x:top style="thin">
                <x:color rgb="FF000000" />
            </x:top>
            <x:bottom style="thin">
                <x:color rgb="FF000000" />
            </x:bottom>
            <x:diagonal />
        </x:border>
    </x:borders>
    <x:cellStyleXfs count="1">
        <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" />
    </x:cellStyleXfs>
    <x:cellXfs count="4">
        <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" />
        <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="1" fillId="0" borderId="1" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="2" fillId="0" borderId="1" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" applyBorder="1" />
        <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="1" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" applyBorder="1" />
    </x:cellXfs>
</x:styleSheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel is limited to a [palette of 56 colors](http://www.officewriter.com/blog/2013/05/08/excels-color-palette-explained). The indexes are stored rather than the actual RGB value as you have provided. I don't know how you are generating the xmls, but your font node should look something like this:

```
<x:fonts count="1">
    <x:font>
        <x:b />
        <x:sz val="12" />
        <x:color theme="1" />
        <x:name val="Arial" />
    </x:font>
</x:fonts>
```

If you use C# or VBA then you can set Colors to your liking by accessing [Workbook.Colors Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-colors-property-excel)

**EDIT**

Like for fonts, borders need to store indexes rather than the actual RGB value as you have provided. Your border node should be something like:

```
<x:left style="thin">
    <x:color indexed="64" />
</x:left>
```

also note, borders need to defined in the correct order: left, right, top, bottom, diagonal. Seems correct in your xml but nevertheless thought of mentioning it here.

This is a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15811904/3110695)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem is not fonts nodes, I removed the fonts node and the error still happens, it is an error on the style xml, I still just can't figure out what it is

Comment: I also though that I needed the index for the color but it seems that you can either do both...