# Open Xml style colors are not showing properly

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using OpenXml for Office SDK to create a spreadsheet. I am having trouble getting the cell background colors working properly.
Any cell I try to apply a background color to shows as black.

Here is an excerpt of my xml that gets generated:

```
<x:styleSheet xmlns:x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main" xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:x16r2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/02/main" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" mc:Ignorable="x14ac x16r2 xr" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <x:fonts count="10">
    <x:font>
      <x:sz val="14" />
      <x:name val="Calibri" />
    </x:font>
    <x:font>
      <x:sz val="12" />
      <x:name val="Calibri" />
    </x:font>
    <x:font>
      <x:sz val="12" />
      <x:name val="Arial" />
    </x:font>
    <x:font>
      <x:sz val="10" />
      <x:name val="Calibri" />
    </x:font>
    <x:font>
      <x:sz val="9" />
      <x:name val="Arial" />
    </x:font>
    <x:font>
      <x:sz val="10" />
      <x:name val="Century Schoolbook" />
    </x:font>
    <x:font>
      <x:sz val="11" />
      <x:name val="Times New Roman" />
    </x:font>
    <x:font>
      <x:sz val="11" />
      <x:name val="Arial" />
    </x:font>
    <x:font>
      <x:sz val="10" />
      <x:name val="Arial" />
    </x:font>
    <x:font>
      <x:sz val="11" />
      <x:name val="Calibri" />
    </x:font>
  </x:fonts>
  <x:fills count="9">
    <x:fill>
      <x:patternFill patternType="none" />
    </x:fill>
    <x:fill>
      <x:patternFill patternType="gray125" />
    </x:fill>
    <x:fill>
      <x:patternFill patternType="solid">
        <x:bgColor rgb="FFFF9900" />
      </x:patternFill>
    </x:fill>
    <x:fill>
      <x:patternFill patternType="solid">
        <x:bgColor rgb="FFFFCC99" />
      </x:patternFill>
    </x:fill>
    <x:fill>
      <x:patternFill patternType="solid">
        <x:bgColor rgb="FF000000" />
      </x:patternFill>
    </x:fill>
    <x:fill>
      <x:patternFill patternType="solid">
        <x:bgColor rgb="FFFFFF99" />
      </x:patternFill>
    </x:fill>
    <x:fill>
      <x:patternFill patternType="solid">
        <x:bgColor rgb="FFFFCC00" />
      </x:patternFill>
    </x:fill>
    <x:fill>
      <x:patternFill patternType="solid">
        <x:bgColor rgb="FFC0C0C0" />
      </x:patternFill>
    </x:fill>
    <x:fill>
      <x:patternFill patternType="solid">
        <x:bgColor rgb="FFFFFF00" />
      </x:patternFill>
    </x:fill>
  </x:fills>
  <x:borders count="1">
    <x:border>
      <x:left />
      <x:right />
      <x:top />
      <x:bottom />
      <x:diagonal />
    </x:border>
  </x:borders>
  <x:cellStyleXfs count="1">
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" />
  </x:cellStyleXfs>
  <x:cellXfs count="23">
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="1" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="1" fillId="1" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="2" fillId="1" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="3" fillId="3" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="4" fillId="4" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="4" fillId="5" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="4" fillId="6" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="8" fillId="7" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="8" fillId="4" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="9" fillId="4" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="1" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="2" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="4" fillId="4" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="5" fillId="4" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="2" fillId="4" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="6" fillId="4" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="7" fillId="4" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="8" fillId="4" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="9" fillId="4" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="9" fillId="8" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" />
  </x:cellXfs>
  <x:cellStyles count="1">
    <x:cellStyle name="Normal" xfId="0" builtinId="0" />
  </x:cellStyles>
  <x:dxfs count="0" />
  <x:tableStyles count="0" defaultTableStyle="TableStyleMedium2" defaultPivotStyle="PivotStyleLight16" />
  <x:extLst>
    <x:ext xmlns:x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main" uri="{EB79DEF2-80B8-43e5-95BD-54CBDDF9020C}">
      <x14:slicerStyles defaultSlicerStyle="SlicerStyleLight1" />
    </x:ext>
    <x:ext xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main" uri="{9260A510-F301-46a8-8635-F512D64BE5F5}">
      <x15:timelineStyles defaultTimelineStyle="TimeSlicerStyleLight1" />
    </x:ext>
  </x:extLst>
</x:styleSheet>
```

The code used to generate it looks like this:

fillList is just a List if Colors

```
            Fills fillsNode = new Fills() { Count = GetUint(_fillList.Count)};
            foreach (System.Drawing.Color color in _fillList) {
                fillsNode.AppendChild(GetFill(color.R, color.G, color.B));
            }
            stylesheet1.Append(fillsNode);
```

These functions are used to create the Fill object and translate r, g and b values to the formatted hex string. This is one of the places I suspect I may be going wrong.

```
        private Fill GetFill(int r, int g, int b) {
            PatternFill pf1 = new PatternFill { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
            pf1.Append(new BackgroundColor() { Rgb = GetHexStringFromRgb(r, g, b)});
            Fill f1 = new Fill();
            f1.Append(pf1);
            return f1;
        }

        private string GetHexStringFromRgb(int r, int g, int b) {


            return $"FF{r.ToString("X2")}{g.ToString("X2")}{b.ToString("X2")}";
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839512/how-to-work-with-style-index-in-open-xml/